# Web page structure comparison using python

Tags: python, dom, data-science

I want to classify a given set of web pages to different classes, mainly to 3 classes(product page, index page and product-related items page). I think it can be done using analyzing their structure. I just look for comparing the web pages based on their DOM(Document Object Model) structure. I want to whether there is library in python for resolving this problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to identify which elements in the page actually uniquely identify a page as being of a specific webpage-class.

Then you could use a library like BeautifulSoup to actually look through the document to see if those elements exist.

Then you would just need a series of if/elifs to determine if a page has the qualifying elements, if so classify it as the appropriate webpage-class.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I looked into web pages. Some web pages divided their structure based on <div> tag, but some other divided on <table> tag. And both websites also contains <div> and <table> tag for other purposes also. So confusion about how to generally classify these items is still not resolved.